# mkdir command not working inside shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts, ssh, sshpass

I have a shell script in one server (Ubuntu) say server1, in which i create a folder in other server say server2. But the command for create directory is not working. Folder is not creating in server2 when i run the script. But if i run the script directly from commandline it creates folder in the server2. Here is the script file :

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p 'xyz' ssh server2@xx.xx.xx.xx '[ -d /var/www/html/Database/Backup/Backups/05-08-2018 ]'

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo 'Directory exists'
else
  echo 'Not exists! Creatting'
  sshpass -p 'xyz' ssh server2@xx.xx.xx.xx  "mkdir -p /var/www/html/Database/Backup/Backups/05-08-2018"
fi
```

What might be the problem here? Can anyone look into it and help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing **sudo** while calling the script helped me resolving the issue. It is working without **sudo**